# Which one is a better data design or object model?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, oop, database-design

**Overview**

I am designing a mechanism for generating dynamic controls in an ASP.NET MVC application that uses ADO.NET Entity Framework. However, my question has nothing to do with MVC and a little to do with the Entity Framework. It is about comparing two object models.

**Problem Statement**

In my app, a user must have the ability to interact with **Web page A** to specify that he wants to add such and such HTML controls to **Web Page B**.

When he browses **Web Page B** next, he must see those controls and be able to use them.

**What Is *Not* The Challenge**

I have written the code to *generate* the controls. That was the easy part. I used the Tag Builder, Partial Views, HtmlHelper extensions and Display & Editor templates.

**The Challenge**
The challenge is in arriving at a database design and an object model generated by Entity Framework to hold the metadata about the controls that need to be generated.

I have come up with a database design as shown below:

[image: Database Diagram]

You may ignore the *User* and *Permissions* tables. They are not relevant to our discussion.

Entity Framework generates the following entities based on the above database design.

[image: Entity Framework Model based on the database design]

Let's call my database design as **Design Option A**.

I would have wanted a design that looked more like this:

[image: An Object Model I Would Have Liked To Have: A More Intuitive Option]

Let's call this second design as **Design Option B**.

The code (stripped down version) for this second option would look like this:

```
namespace DynamicControls
{
    public class DynamicControlGroup
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Controller { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> Actions { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        public User CreatedByUser { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }

        public User LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime ModificationDateTime { get; set; }

        // Navigational
        public ICollection<DynamicControl<T>> DynamicControls { get; set; }
    }

    public class DynamicControl<T>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; } //db Id

        public string HtmlId { get; set; }

        public bool ValueRequired { get; set; }

        public virtual ControlType ControlType { get; protected set; }

        // Every control is capable of having a default value but of a different
        // type. Most controls have default values of type text (string). The
        // multi-select ones (checkboxes, multi-select lists, etc.) have a default
        // value of type IEnumerable<string>. So, I want to leave this generic.
        // But I am not that hung-up on this. I am fine if I am required to move
        // this property DefaultValue from the base class and make it a concrete 
        // (not generic) property for each individual child class.

        // Mostly I just want the heirarchy. And before that, I want to know
        // if it is a good idea to model this heirarchy. Or is it better to just
        // work with what my Entity Framework produced for my db?

        // Should I change my db? I can because I thought-up the design for
        // those tables.
        public virtual T DefaultValue { get; set; }

        // Navigational
        public DynamicControlGroup DynamicControlGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public class TextBox : DynamicControl<string>
    {
        public override ControlType ControlType
        {
            get
            {
                return DynamicControls.ControlType.TextBox;
            }
        }

        public string Label { get; set; }

        public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    }

    public class PasswordControl : TextBox
    {
        public override ControlType ControlType
        {
            get
            {
                return DynamicControls.ControlType.Password;
            }
        }
    }

    public class TextArea : TextBox
    {
        public override ControlType ControlType
        {
            get
            {
                return DynamicControls.ControlType.TextArea;
            }
        }

        public int Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class DropDownList: DynamicControl<string>
    {
        public override ControlType ControlType
        {
            get
            {
                return ControlType.DropDownList;
            }
        }

        // I want something like this. That I should be able to say
        //
        // myDropDownListObject.Options...
        // 
        // You'll notice that given my current database design, I have
        // no direct way of accessing the options of a, say, drop down list.
        // To do that, I have to make a round-about Linq query.
        public ICollection<DynamicControlOption> Options { get; set; }
    }

    public class DynamicControlOption
    {
        public long Id { get; set; } // db Id

        public string OptionHtmlId { get; set; }

        public string OptionValue { get; set; }

        public string OptionText { get; set; }

        // Navigational property
        public DynamicControl<IEnumerable<string>> TheControlWhoseOptionIAm { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
    }

    public class Permission
    {
    }

    public enum ControlType
    {
        TextBox,
        TextArea,
        Password,
        RadioButton,
        Checkbox,
        DropDownList,
        MultiSelectList,
        DatePicker,
        TimePicker,
        DateTimePicker
    }
}
```

**My Question**
1) I feel that I'd like Design Option B better. Am I feeling right?

2) I know I can work with **Design Option A** just as fine but it'll involve a little round-about way to do some things. For example, to get all the options for a drop down list, there's not navigational property on the DropDownList class in **Design Option A**. I'll have to write a round-about Linq query to do that.

3) Is it possible to have Entity Framework come close to generating **Design Option B**? How? What changes will I need to make to my database design to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Now we are working on a Project like this at our company...
If I got your meaning correctly and If I were you...I implemented inherited structure as my  database design like below.
Now you Classes are inheritance but your database design is not.

I have removed **Id** in **TextBox** and I have put **ControlId** as PK and FK in the same time. (not just FK).

in fact,ControlId is both **PK** for **TextBox** and **FK** from **DynamicControl**
and also this way for **PasswordControl** and **TextArea**

and Now  **ControlId** in **TextBox** is not *Identity*. It gets it's  **ControlId** from **DynamicControl**

[image]

I also accept **Design Option B** .I'm always more comfortable than using **Design Option A**.in my idea It's true and main structure

Comment: Thank you, Fuad. You are quite right. That helped much, but wasn't completely necessary. I looked up my old books and remembered that there was something called Table Per Type Hierarchy/Inheritance in the Entity Framework. I used that.

Comment: I'm really happy.Your Welcome friend.You know ... I think what you wanted about creating an inheritance relation by using Entity Framework is not possible,isn't it?... because sql can't find out inheritance relation.Sql can just create join relation,isn't it? May you can implement it manually and replace and turn those joined relations into inheritance in VS...anyway...you seems more experienced than me friend :) I just wanted to help you and myself

Comment: Hey, you're too kind. I am not better than anyone. I suck big time. I am getting old and I just keep asking questions to solve problems. You're awesome!